# Google Calendar API doesn't send the email to attendees

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API to create an event and send an invite email to attendees.

The event is created, I'm seeing the invitation in my calendar, but I never received the email for this new event.

This is the code that I'm using:

```js
function handleAddEventClick() {
  var event = {
    'summary': 'xxxxxxxx',
    'location': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'description': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'start': {
      'dateTime': '2024-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
      'timeZone': 'America/Santiago'
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': '2024-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
      'timeZone': 'America/Santiago'
    },
    'attendees': [{
      'email': 'name@mail.com'
    }],
    'reminders': {
      'useDefault': false,
      'overrides': [{
          'method': 'email',
          'minutes': 24 * 60
        },
        {
          'method': 'popup',
          'minutes': 10
        }
      ],
      'transparency': 'opaque',
      'visibility': 'private'
    }
  };
  
  var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    'calendarId': primary,
    'resource': event,
    'sendUpdates': 'all'
  });
}
```

The function `sendNotification` was deprecated and I'm trying to use the new method available: `sendUpdates`.

Google said that it works for creation and modification but in my code it works just when modifying the event.